# How to run a custom Geoprocessing tool using no parameters?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, geoprocessing, arctoolbox

I created a custom geoprocessing tool called "CreateCoverLayer". It has no input or output parameters.  I have the following snippet of code, but get an error message due to the fact that the `Execute` method is looking for an array of parameters as the second input argument. Can I use this tool with no parameters, or is that not possible?  Thanks!

```cs
IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();    
gp.AddToolbox(@"C:\TestToolbox.tbx");
gp.Execute("CreateCoverLayer", null, null);
```

Comment: Did you try passing an empty array?

Comment: Yes, I also tried this . . .

Comment: IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass();    
gp.AddToolbox(@"C:\TestToolbox.tbx");
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();gp.Execute("CreateCoverLayer", parameters, null);

Comment: That should work. What happens when you use an empty `IVariantArray`?

Comment: The above code (sending in the empty array) did work, so I'm all set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code did work . . .

```
IGeoProcessor2 gp = new GeoProcessorClass(); 
gp.AddToolbox(@"C:\TestToolbox.tbx"); 
IVariantArray parameters = new VarArrayClass();
gp.Execute("CreateCoverLayer", parameters, null);
```

Sending in the empty array did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the geoprocessor managed assembly instead of the geoprocessing one. You can call execute without a parameter variable, as shown with the system delete below, but im not sure what it will do with a custom tool.

```
Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
DeleteFeatures delete = new DeleteFeatures();
delete.in_features = layer;
gp.Execute(delete, null);
```

Comment: Yes, I've also used this type of code and was successful . . .

Comment: ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor GP = new ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor.Geoprocessor();

            
            CopyFeatures copyFeatures = new CopyFeatures();
                        copyFeatures.in_features = @"C:\FOBSP.gdb\BrigadeAOI";
            copyFeatures.out_feature_class = @"C:\Data\BrigadeAOIcopy.shp";
            RunTool(GP, copyFeatures, null);